# Is there any need to scale data in SVM if my weight vector is binary in nature?

Tags: svm, libsvm

My weight vector is SVM training (using *Libsvm*) will have only feature number and then 1 or 0 i.e representing whether present or NOT present.

it would be like below *libsvm* format.

```
1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:1...9600:1
0 1:1 2:0 3:1 4:0...9600:0
....
```

As all the measurements are based on one criteria whether present or not? Will scaling be a issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, scaling should not be an issue, because scaling basically does that :  scale your data back to a 0-1 range.